# I tried to add Python to VSCode, but it won't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord

I opened command prompt (I'm on Windows) and I typed:

'''none
pip3 install discord
'''

Then it said it installed discord, and I was ready to go! (I already had Python 3.9.7 installed)
Then when I opened VSCode up and typed:   `import discord`   I got this error message:

> "discord" is not accessedPylance
>
> Import "discord" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

What does this mean, and how can I fix it? I was really looking forward to coding the bot, but don't know how, now that this is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

check in the bottom left corner of the VS Code window for which version of Python is it using. This issue usually occurs for me when I’m working in a virtual environment but VS Code is pointing to my global Python installation.

Comment: python 3.9.7 (windows store) is the version

Comment: I also did python 3.9.7 not from Microsoft store and that didn't work either

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `Python Interpreter` in `VSCODE` to solve this issue.

---

1. Open settings in `VSCODE` by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`. Make sure your `.py` file is open while doing this step.

2. Search there `Python: Select Interpreter` and choose the right version.
3. Reload `VSCODE` and see if it works!

Comment: Thank you Fareed Khan! Which version is the "right version?" 3.8 (Conda), 3.9.7, and 3.10 did not work. Any others I should try? If so, how do I add those?

Comment: @Novakron, May I ask how did you restart your `VSCODE`?. You have to restart it by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `P` and type there `reload window!`. You have installed `discord` using `cmd`, it should be installed in any of these version you mentioned so only problem is to select right `interpreter`  in `VSCODE`.

Answer (score 0):

Open an **integrated** Terminal in VS Code,

1. run `python --version`, it should be `python3.9.7` which is selected as python interpreter and shown in status bar.
2. run `pip show discord` to check if its location is `\..\python3.9.3\lib\site-packages`. If not, reinstall it.